# jshint rejects regex - why?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, ecmascript-6, jshint

```
# cat test.js
function foo() {
    var bmp = /^[\u{0020}-\u{007e}\u{00A0}-\u{FFFF}]+$/u;
}

# jshint test.js
test.js: line 2, col 15, Invalid regular expression.
test.js: line 2, col 56, Missing semicolon.
test.js: line 2, col 56, Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

3 errors

# jshint -v
jshint v2.9.5
```

I've seen posts elsewhere about older versions of jshint rejecting valid regexes. Is this a case of that, or is something wrong with my expression? https://regex101.com claims that it is okay with the JavaScript engine in full unicode mode.

I have the same problem with:

```
var combine = /[\u{0020}-\u{007e}\u{00A0}-\u{0300}\u{036F}-\u{1AB0}\u{1AFF}-\u{1DC0}\u{1DCF}-\u{20D0}\u{20FF}-\u{FE20}\u{FE2F}-\u{FFFF}]/u;
```

For bonus points, if this *is* a jshint limitation, can I tell it to ignore this line? I have insufficient control over our build environment to upgrade to a later version of jshint.

Comment: [This regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Gr2JwT/1) clearly shows errors for the dashes in the pattern. May it be possible that jshint does not understand the unicode modifier?

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp See https://regex101.com/r/rO06B7/1, you forgot `u` modifier.

Comment: Hmm just discovered `/u` is new in ECMAScript 6? As such, given my target platforms, I have bigger problems than jshint rejecting it.

Comment: @ctwheels: That would actually mean something different (see https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#unicode-code-point for the meaning of `\u{nnnn}`). And it still fails, although this time without the first error message line

Comment: What *bigger problems* you are talking about?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit very interesting, thanks for the link! I've removed my comment to prevent confusion to future readers

Comment: @revo: Does "it won't work" count? ;) I can't use these Unicode-aware regexes at all, since not all of my target browsers support them (for example, IE10 and IE11). So what I thought was a false alarm from jshint has (perhaps accidentally) revealed that I just fundamentally can't use this feature. A shame but 
https://mothereff.in/regexpu seems to have saved the day...

Comment: At this point I'm not sure how common JSHint usage is. The vast majority of the community has switched to ESLint. Something to keep in mind anyway. I know you said you can't control that currently.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: In fairness it's not that I don't have control, it's that I decline to replace all my build server images just for jshint - so, at the very least, I can consider migrating to ESLint (TIL) in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that jshint doesn't support ES6's Unicode-aware regular expressions (or `\u{....}` literals more generally) yet (at time of writing, the most recent release is v2.9.5).

See the following open issues:

- https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/2361
- https://github.com/jshint/jshint/pull/2413

Therefore, this can't work. I don't know whether you can suppress checking on this line without the parser just breaking more generally.

However, it turns out some of your target browsers (IE10 and IE11) don't support these features either, so the point is moot.

---

#### Workaround

Transpile the regexes into valid ES5 (using [regexpu](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/regexpu), or [an online interface to the same](https://mothereff.in/regexpu)), resulting in the following:

```
var bmp = /^(?:[ -~\xA0-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF](?![\uDC00-\uDFFF])|(?:[^\uD800-\uDBFF]|^)[\uDC00-\uDFFF])+$/;
```

and:

```
var combine = /(?:[ -~\xA0-\u0300\u036F-\u1AB0\u1AFF-\u1DC0\u1DCF-\u20D0\u20FF-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFE20\uFE2F-\uFFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF](?![\uDC00-\uDFFF])|(?:[^\uD800-\uDBFF]|^)[\uDC00-\uDFFF])/;
```

Correctness yet to be entirely ascertained, but I have little reason to doubt the tool.